# ClassNotFoundException when deploying EAR on WebLogic Server

Tags: weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy an EAR on a WebLogic Server 12, which contains an EJB module (.jar) and a GUI module (.war). The structure of the EAR is the following :

```
+-- APP-INF
|   +-- lib
|       +-- jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
|       +-- jackson-core-2.5.3.jar
|       +-- jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar
|       +-- jackson-dataformat-csv-2.5.3.jar
|       +-- mapstruct-1.2.0.Final.jar
|       +-- mapstruct-processor-1.2.0.Final.jar
+-- META-INF
|   +-- application.xml
|   +-- weblogic-application.xml
|   +-- MANIFEST.MF
+-- jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
+-- jackson-core-2.5.3.jar
+-- jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar
+-- jackson-dataformat-csv-2.5.3.jar
+-- mapstruct-1.2.0.Final.jar
+-- mapstruct-processor-1.2.0.Final.jar
+-- my-ejb-module.jar
+-- my-gui-module.war
```

The content of my `weblogic-application.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd 
                                              http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application 
                                              http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">

    <!-- Paramètre l'encodage en UTF-8 -->
    <wls:application-param>
        <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
        <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
    </wls:application-param>

    <!-- Activation du filtre classloader pour log4J -->
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.mapstruct.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.taglibs.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>org.mapstruct.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>javax.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.apache.taglibs.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:resource-name>

        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.FacesConfigResourceProvider</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

But when I deploy the EAR via the `wlfullclient.jar`, I have the folowwing error :

```
Target state: deploy failed on Server xxx
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.FormatSchema
```

But the class is located in the jackson-core-2.5.3.jar, maybe I am missing something ? I can not figure out what is the mistake here. Unfortunately, I have already searched on Google but the answers that I've found did not solve my problem.

Comment: Why did you place your libes in APP-INF/lib and at the root of the application ? Can you try to remove librairies at the root.

Comment: It seems that the JARs at the root are automatically added by maven at compile time. However, I have already tried to remove them, but I'm still facing the issue.

Comment: How do you deploy your application ? Console, wlst, weblogic.Deployer ?

Comment: Using wlfullclient.jar weblogic.Deployer (in command line)